# Python 3 input() function not allowing input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I haven't really ran into many issues with python but I'm working on a side project and the input() function wasn't working. I created a new file to test out a simple input() function and the same thing happened, the program doesn't take any input and it instead seems to take in the pyenv version or something? Anyone know how to fix this?

```py
# Taking input from the user
name = input("Enter your name")
 
# Print input
print("Hello", name)
```

Pasted output from terminal:

```
Enter your namepyenv shell 2.7.18

Hello pyenv shell 2.7.18
```

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you running it from an IDE console or a terminal window?

Comment: You're running your script with Python 2. Don't!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, when I run python --version in my terminal it tells me I have python 3.8.9, is it still running with Python 2? How do I update it?

Comment: You have to start python3 ... If you run `python` the systems default version is used and it seems to be the python2 one.

Comment: if you use an IDE like `vscode` then you can select the version of python that you want to run.

Comment: How can I do that?? I use VSCode this must be the issue

Comment: By the way: in python2 you ask for user input with `raw_input()` as `input()` as such works not like the `input()` in python3.